# Angular 13 + Asciidoctor.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of function 'function()

Tags: angular, typescript, asciidoctor

I'm trying to experiment with how to use Asciidoctor.js in Angular 13 apps.
I created my app using:

```
ng new Test-Asciidoctor --strict --routing --style=scss
```

and followed the documentation at https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor.js/latest/setup/install/#typescript
to import the Asciidoctor processor.

```
import Processor from 'asciidoctor'

const processor = Processor()
```

but it results in the following error:

[image]

[image]

It seems like the function prototype doesn't allow to modify
the length property. How can I allow it to make the Asciidoctor.js work in Angular?

**Update**

Considering some links related to this problem, the issue appears to be related with the strict mode.

- https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor.js/latest/setup/install/#typescript

However, the same error happens also with the strict mode turned off:

```
ng new Test-Asciidoctor --strict=false --routing --style=scss
```

Comment: That's very odd code. While it could be "fixed" by disabling strict mode, looks like asciidoctor is in need of some restructuring. This is one of the reasons why functions usually shouldn't be treated as objects to put arbitrary key-value pairs on.

Comment: Here there is an answer confirming the strict mode issue. I hope they will fix this. https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.js/issues/686#issuecomment-564095298

Comment: I tried to generate a new Angular 13 app with `--strict=false` but the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround for my project by preloading it with html script balise.
like :

```html
    <script src="@asciidoctor/asciidoctor.js"></script>
    <script>
      window._gvAsciidoctor = Asciidoctor();
    </script>
```

inside index.html

```
"assets": [
...

              {
                "glob": "asciidoctor.js",
                "input": "node_modules/@asciidoctor/core/dist/browser",
                "output": "@asciidoctor/"
              },
...
]
```

inside angular.json

then i can use window._gvAsciidoctor in my esm modules dependencies to interact or add extensions

it's not very clean but I haven't found better for the moment